# Mysql version for Slick

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I updated my Play app with Scala 2.12 and Play 2.6.1, also I've changed Slick to v3.2 . Before (Scala 2.11.11 and Play 2.5.14) everything was working fine with Mysql driver version 5.1.23, which is the officially supported version, as said in this page: https://github.com/slick/slick . Now I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: slick.driver.MySQLDriver
```

Also after several sbt clean. Is there any form of dependence between mysql driver and scala?

Comment: How are you building/running the application? Are you using an IDE? I ask b/c I recently did something similiar using Jetbrains IDEA, and I had to  set the slick.driver.MySQLDriver library to be available at compile time or runtime(I can't remember exactly which).

Comment: nope, I compile from terminal and I use Notepad++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was obvious maybe, but I searched in the docs: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/api/#slick.driver.package
and the driver package has changed from slick.driver to slick.jdbc.(db)Profile,
so now

```
slick.driver.MySQLDriver
```

became

```
slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile
```